# SUMIF cells that header contains text return 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sun cells that contain the word "time" but return zero

```
=SUMIF(Attendance!60:60,"*Time*",Attendance!61:61)
```

[photo of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiFbO.png)

My attendance sheet:

| row 60 | Time | # | Time2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row 61 | 60 | 1 | 90 |

[photo of attendance sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCNX4.png)

Answer (score 1):

In cell `F2` you can have the following:

```
=SUMIF(A1:D1,"Time*",A2:D2)
```

This is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

Check [SUMIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) documentation, you can use wildcards.

Comment: I meant rows 60 and 61
I need this sum in another sheet and this way only returns 0

Comment: @Erfane please work more on your question, It is not clear to me the ask and why having two sheets make the difference. Please update the question not adding comments, the question should have all necessary information to understand the problem. My answer response to your requirements based on the sample data.