# Sum the values that are in the same columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum the values that are in the "Time" columns but return 0
[image: Please see the photo]

I tried the following formula:

=SUMIF(C2:H2,"Time*",C3:H3)

=SUMIF(SCRATCH031342[#Headers],"Time*",C3:H3)

Comment: Strange that `=SUMIF(C2:H2,"Time*",C3:H3)` wouldn't work. Because it should! Are these text values instead of numbers (based on the green triangles I assume they are)?  And are there invisible characters? Leading spaces will mess this up and return 0 for example.

Comment: Per my understanding  @Erfane your are creating a second question from this initial one: [SUMIF cells that header contains text return 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74180845/sumif-cells-that-header-contains-text-return-0) that seems to be the same, instead of improving the initial question with the information you provided in this question. This makes this question duplicated. Please clarify it. If this is the case this question should be labeled as duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

### Sum Up Numbers As Text

For the first row of data, you could use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(C$2:H$2,4)="Time"),VALUE(C3:H3))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(SCRATCH031342[#Headers],4)="Time"),VALUE(C3:H3))
```

and copy down.

Additionally, if you'll write the results in the same row as the table row (e.g. in cell `J3`), you should simplify the table version with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(SCRATCH031342[#Headers],4)="Time"),VALUE(SCRATCH031342[@]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(C3:H4,0,MATCH(C6,C2:H2,0)))
```

and fill in cell `C6` with the desired column name